# Can the Live Agent REST API be used server-side to manage multiple chat sessions at the same time?

Tags: rest-api, liveagent

I'd like to build a server side integration with the Live Agent Rest API that allows me to forward messages from multiple users to the live agents, but it seems to be that REST API is built to be used client side by a single chat interface, and I need to be querying incoming messages for each chat session, which really does not scale well, is there a way to bypass that?

Some context: I work building chatbots and I've developed a custom web chat plugin as well as integrated several chat apps like Twitter, Facebook, Telegram, etc. I am looking for a way to have Salesforce live agents reply to those chats when the users want to talk to a real human.